# Animate ul li.active within view site

Tags: jquery, events, animation, html-lists

I have a pagination like this

```
<div> ( =400px )
<ul> ( =2000px )
<li>1<div>1</div></li>
<li>2<div>2</div></li>
<li>3<div>3</div></li>
..
</ul>
</div>
```

The pagination goes up to 100 and is about 2000px width. However, the div is only 400px width with `overflow:hidden` This means only a certain amount of `li` is visible. I also have two buttons do do animation left and right, this way a visitor can 'slide' left and right trought the pagination:

```
$(".right").live('click', function(){
  $(ul).animate({"left": "-=140px"}, "fast");
});

$(".left").live('click', function(){
  $(ul).animate({"left": "+=140px"}, "fast");
});
```

The problem is that at a certain point the 'active'(Class) pagination number is out of sight (the reason is not important in this question)

I would like to have control over the `li.active` trough whatever Jquery event or on document ready. I would like the `li.active` to be visible in 400px div all the time. So that means the ul would move left or right relative to the `li.active` so that the `li.active` will not be in the part that is 'hidden' (overflow:hidden)

I hope my question is clear, I cant post all the code do to its big size. (it would only complicate things..)

Comment: With that many pages, would it not make more sense to have the following pagination links structure: `first|prev|-10|-5|-4|-3|-2|-1|current|+1|+2|+3|+4|+5|+10|[INPUT - Type page num.]`

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Im not sure what you mean..but I think you are referring to dynamic pagination, mine are more physical(in the HTML)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, my only guess is add a css rule on "active" class with `position:absolute;`

**EDIT :**

Try [this solution here](http://jsfiddle.net/JVXpu/12/), if it's what you're looking for. I hope it helps!

Comment: The class active is part of the entire list. The problem is not positioning .active but the entire ul li 'relative' to .active. So the ul li has to move along with it (up to 'view port')

Comment: can u make it on jsfiddle.com presentation to demonstrate a valid example of your problem?

Comment: I made a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JVXpu/ How do I get the red number in the view port, which is the green bordered div, using jquery event or on document ready.

Comment: I edited the above post and gave you a solution! Let me know if it was of any help or not! :)

Comment: Thanks, exactly (well kinda) what I was looking for:) Don't no if its going to work eventually in what Im working on, but its definitely a good answer.